# How can I adjust time by timezones in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone

How do I use a different time zone time in a JavaScript?

I already know how to get the current system time but I am confused how to display different time zone time. This one is displaying as an alert, but I need it as a usual displayer not as an alert.

```
function calcTime(city, offset) {
    d = new Date();

    utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
    nd = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));

    return "The local time in " + city + " is " + nd.toLocaleString();
}

alert(calcTime('U.S.A', '-5.0'));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to initialize javascript date to a particular timezone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141762/how-to-initialize-javascript-date-to-a-particular-timezone)

Answer (score 0):

The "time" is *absolute*.

How you *display* the time (including time zone) is *representational*.

So the key thing to understand is that you *DON'T* want to modify the time  *VALUE* - you just need to alter your *FORMAT* statement to use one or another time zone.

For example, this uses the [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) timezone plugin:

`moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format("h:mm a")`

Here is a great reference:

[Stack Overflow 'Timezone' tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info)